# jSonString to PHP in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I send from an iOs Device a jsonString

That looks like this:

```
2012-10-10 08:50:32.011 Appname[4049:c07] Post String =http://www.yourdomain.nl/locatie.php?data=%7B%22id%22:%220612833397%22,%22longitude%22:%22-143.406417%22,%22latitude%22:%2232.785834%22,%22timestamp%22:%2210-10%2007:56%22%7D
```

That is when i NSLog it...

So the PHP file looks something like this:

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$timestamp = $_POST['stringFromDate'];



$link = mysql_connect('server', 'sbla', 'bla')
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('md267052db227433') or die('Could not select database');

// Performing SQL query
$query = "INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp) VALUES (NULL," .   $longitude . "," . $latitude . "," .$timestamp." )";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
echo "OK";


// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

When i go to yourdomain.nl/locatie.php it says that the it is empty, but that should be because i send the data from my iOs app.

I want that the jSonstring that i can see the id, longitude, latitude and timestamp and put them in my mySQL database, but it strangely doenst work.

I know that the string from the iOs device was sended.

Sorry for my bad english,

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Send it like this:

```
- (void)myFuntionThatWritesToDatabaseInBackgroundWithLatitude:(NSString *)latitude longitude:(NSString *)longitude date:

(NSString *)stringFromDate {


_phonenumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"phoneNumber"];

NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];
NSString*jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{\"id\":\"%@\",\"longitude\":\"%@\",\"latitude\":\"%@\",\"timestamp\":\"%@\"}",_phonenumber, longitude , latitude, stringFromDate];

[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?data=%@", jsonString]];
[postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];


[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self ];
NSLog(@"Post String =%@", postString);


//    LocationTestViewController*locationTestViewController = [[LocationTestViewController alloc]init];
//    phonenumber = locationTestViewController.telefoonnummer;
NSLog(@"telnr : %@", _phonenumber);

NSURLResponse* response;
NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse;
NSError* error;
NSData* responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString* stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
int statuscode = [httpResponse statusCode];

if (statuscode == 200)
{
    NSLog(@"Verstuurd");
    // Handle the response here if needed
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"niet verstuurd: %@", stringResponse);
    // Show some form of alert here if needed
}
// release all objects saved to memory
[request release];
request = nil;
[stringResponse release];
stringResponse = nil;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is not JSON, its POST FORMDATA probably. Second, when you open the link (with a browser) - it becomes a GET request, not a POST. Try logging the $_POST in file when doing the request from the iOS device. Like this (first line of PHP file):

```
file_put_contents('dump.txt', "POST: \n" . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n\n\n GET: \n" . print_r($_GET, true));
```

Then do several requests to see the results in "dump.txt" in same dir.

Also, the query should look like this (if I have guessed your colums right):

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO locatie (longitude, latitude, timestamp) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%d')", mysql_real_escape_string($longitude), mysql_real_escape_string($latitude), (int)$timestamp)  ;
```

The PHP manual discourages usage of the `mysql_real_escape_string` though - more on this here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

**EDIT:**

My mistake, so the POSTed data is in fact JSON string - try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
    $latitude = $data['latitude'];
    $longitude = $data['longitude'];
    $timestamp = $data['stringFromDate'];
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: POST: 
Array
(
)



 GET: 
Array
(
)

Comment: Well, then this is invalid: `2012-10-10 08:50:32.011 Appname[4049:c07] Post String =http://www.yourdomain.nl/locatie.php?data=%7B%22id%22:%220612833397%22,%22longitude%22:%22-143.406417%22,%22latitude%22:%2232.785834%22,%22timestamp%22:%2210-10%2007:56%22%7D` 

Give us more info about how you perform the POST.

Comment: Oh wait: now its like this: POST: 
Array
(
)



 GET: 
Array
(
    [data] => {"id":"0612833397","longitude":"-143.406417","latitude":"32.785834","timestamp":"10-10 07:56"}
)

Comment: And no: my colums are all strings @Veseliq

Comment: Check my edit, the database column values should be set accordingly - I don't know your database schema or data format!

Comment: hi, when i do this i get two values in my table.. all the values are NULL except for the timestamp. That's because it isnt a integer

Comment: Well, do a var_dump of the $data from the json_decode. Check the values, check the query you are executing - debug it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17795/discussion-between-babboe-and-veseliq)

Answer (score 0):

You do a GET request and no POST. So you have to get the data with `$_GET` and not with `$_POST`.
You also need to first `json_decode` the string to get the values from it.
You could also send all values with GET without JSON. To do this you just have to send multiple GET parameters like `http://example.org/index.php?key1=parameter1&key2=parameter2`.

Comment: Whats this????? When i do the code it gives me this error: Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', )' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$timestamp = $_POST['stringFromDate'];

$datarray['id']=$id;
$datarray['longitude']=$longitude;
$datarray['latitude']=$latitude ;
$datarray['stringFromDate']=$timestamp;

$link = mysql_connect('db.babboemedia.nl', 'md267052db227433', 't7cjxOm3')
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('md267052db227433') or die('Could not select database');

// Performing SQL query
$query = "INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp) VALUES (NULL," .   $longitude . "," . $latitude . "," .$timestamp." )";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());


// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);



if($result)
{
    $datarray['status']="OK";
}
else
{
    $datarray['stringFromDate']="NOTOK";
}

// Closing connection
mysql_close($link);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
json_encode($datarray);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to check `$_POST['data']` Then strip the slashes. Then parse the JSON.

```
<?php
$json=json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
//print_r($json);
$id = $json['id'];
$longitude = $json['longitude'];
$latitude = $json['latitude'];
$timestamp = $json['stringFromDate'];
//the rest of your code goes here
```

Comment: Not sure why someone gave this answer a thumbs down. The OP is obviously using a post request and sending:
`data=%7B%22id%22:%220612833397%22,%22longitude%22:%22-143.406417%22,%22latitude%22:%2232.785834%22,%22timestamp%22:%2210-10%2007:56%22%7D`

Which only sets the "data" parameter. And if you read the result of the post via PHP you will notice $_POST will contain the JSON as expected yet based on the data sent in there will be a bunch of leading backslashes. So I compensated for that by calling `stripslashes`. I still think I have the best answer so far out of all the answers given.